# Show more fields with a button on ASP

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, button

I'm doing website where the employee can write his resume, i have a section of Past Jobs, and i want to display the fields where the employee can write this info (company, position, etc), but, i want to show just one of those sections, if the employee wants to add more old jobs he will click on the add more and then shows 2 or 3 more fields for those past jobs, currently i have 3 of those sections declared like this:

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Empresa" Style="z-index: 1; left: 10px;
        top: 165px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 80px; top:  165px;
        position: absolute" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Fecha" Style="z-index: 1; left: 10px;
        top: 195px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 80px;
        top: 195px; position: absolute">
        <asp:ListItem>Enero</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Febrero</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Marzo</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Abril</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Mayo</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Junio</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Julio</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Agosto</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Septiembre</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Octubre</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Noviembre</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Diciembre</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 172px;
        top: 195px; position: absolute" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="a" Style="z-index: 1; left: 235px; top: 195px;
        position: absolute"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 250px;
        top: 195px; position: absolute">
        <asp:ListItem>Enero</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Febrero</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Marzo</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Abril</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Mayo</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Junio</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Julio</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Agosto</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Septiembre</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Octubre</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Noviembre</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Diciembre</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 342px;
        top: 195px; position: absolute" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Puesto:" Style="z-index: 1; left: 10px;
        top: 225px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 80px; top: 225px;
        position: absolute" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Funciones:" Style="z-index: 1; left: 10px;
        top: 255px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="z-index: 1;
        left: 80px; top: 255px; position: absolute" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
```

So, i just want to hidden the other 2 and just show them when i click on the button Add More, i'm a really newbie on ASP, and no idea how to do it, and how this can influence the other labels and textboxes i have since everyone has a a position with left and top, if they will be needed to move or what will hapen to them.

I hope i'm explaining my problem and you can help me :D

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnShowMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DropDownList1.Visible=false;
DropDownList2.Visible=false;
DropDownList3.Visible=true;
}
```

And may use properity 'Enabled' if you want the control to be displayed but user can't do actions on it.

Comment: Thanks!! That works but what i want is that what is under the Add More button moves more to the bottom when i click the Add More, because right now just leaves a blank space on the site

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need some javascript magic. You could perform something like this when a button is clicked inside your aspx page. Would just need to have the section you want to toggle have a display attribute of "none" by default (style="display: none"). Then when "Add More" is clicked, the display attribute will change to "block", showing the hidden section :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
        {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else
        {
            e.style.display = 'block';
         }
    }
</script>
```

Then call this javascript function like this where ever the button or link is:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle_visibility('#idOfDiv');">Add More</a>
```

Best of luck!